# Send data when the purchase is complete in PayPal (onApprove)

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to send the data to another php file where I could check and save data into my database when `onApprove` has been completed :

```
 <script>
                                // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
                                function loadAsync(url, callback) {
                            var s = document.createElement('script');
                            s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
                            document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
                            }


                            // Usage -- callback is inlined here, but could be a named function
                            loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD&disable-funding=card', function() {
                            paypal.Buttons({
                                // Set up the transaction
                                createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                                    return actions.order.create({
                                        purchase_units: [{
                                            amount: {
                                                value: <?echo $cart->getCartTotal(true)?>
                                             
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    });
                                },
                                // Finalize the transaction
                                      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            // show loader on screen whilst wating to redirect
            $('.checkout-loader').addClass('active');
            
            // excute php script
            var EXECUTE_URL = 'https://example.com/TESTS.php?success='+success;
            // Authorize the transaction
            actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Call your server to validate and capture the transaction
                return fetch(EXECUTE_URL, {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        orderID     : data.orderID,
                        success : "okaysuc"
                    })
                }).then(function(response){
                    // redirect to the completed page if paid
                    window.location.href = '/success/' + data.orderID;
                });
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                            });
                            </script>
```

And my `TESTS.php` :

```
<?php  
$retour = $_POST['success']; //I have tried json_decode() also, didnt work....
$db->query("INSERT INTO mydbname(order_id) VALUES ('$retour')");   //empty data is added to databse  
$cart = new Cart();
if($retour == 'okaysuc'){
//my code goes here.. But not works because data is empty. it is not sent. 
}
?>
```

Everything works except the `POST`ed variables. I don't know how to send the datas to another php file.
Does somebody know where is the mistake ? I have tried almost all but no success. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Do NOT use actions.order.create() / actions.order.capture() to create/capture orders on the client side, and only later send data to a server after client side events are completed**

Instead, switch to a proper client-server integration. Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Your fetch to the create or capture endpoints should be extended to include a `body` param with any additional data you wish to send, which can be verified for correctness before that action proceeds on the server, and only stored in the event of a successful capture response.

Comment: I am using php, how can't I use the actions.order.capture/create() ? I mean if it would be JS then it would be possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am trying to understand the downside of using `actions.order.capture/create()`. Why shouldn't I use that methods?

Comment: Because very many things can go wrong. You should never use those methods if you intend to do anything with a server.

Comment: Then I stuck forever if I must change that methods even if I am in PHP. I am struggling to find the example with PHP where I can use the methods you mention and send/receive the data and save it to DB. At the moment I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Start with implementing two server routes that call the PayPal API to create and capture an order. You can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK or direct HTTPS API calls.

Comment: I have created the CHECKOUT-PHP-SDK  before trying this JS SDK. And the reason was to use this method was because due to my working logic of website I can't use approval based 2 step payment. I mean my customer shouldn't leave the website and pay, all payment process and approval must be done in a one whole process. either it fails or it successes. I am checking the PHP-SDK which can be found here : `http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html`   and what I can see here is that when the user pays then website needs to approve that process.

Comment: The PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated. Use the current Checkout-PHP-SDK, to create and capture orders. Use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server for the approval flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243258/discussion-between-ali-mammadov-and-preston-phx).